# peekable in Iterators

Tags: rust, iterator

```
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("ADOBECODEBANC");
    let mut iter = s.chars().peekable();
    let it1 = *iter.by_ref().peekable().peek().unwrap();
    println!("{}",it1);
    let t = *iter.peek().unwrap();
    println!("{}",t);
}
```

why in this code t is pointing to D as I have not done next() anywhere ?

Comment: When you call `.peek()` is actually consumes the `.next()` item

Answer (score 0):

> why in this code t is pointing to D as I have not done next() anywhere ?

Given iterators are lazy, and `peekable` has no requirements at all how do you figure it should work?

The answer is that when you `peek()` it calls `next()` on the underlying iterator and stores the result:

```rust
    pub fn peek(&mut self) -> Option<&I::Item> {
        let iter = &mut self.iter;
        self.peeked.get_or_insert_with(|| iter.next()).as_ref()
    }
```

therefore it advances the underlying iterator.

Obviously it first returns the contents of `self.peeked` when iterated:

```rust
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<I::Item> {
        match self.peeked.take() {
            Some(v) => v,
            None => self.iter.next(),
        }
    }
```

so normally you don't see anything amiss, but if you access the underlying iterator separately as you do here you'll see the front element disappear.

Otherwise, either every iterator would need to implement peeking interally (which would make `peek()` a no-op so why even have it) or `peek` would have to be restricted to a class of iterators Rust does not even have (at least a [`bidirectional_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/bidirectional_iterator) in C++ terms, possibly a [`random_access_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/random_access_iterator)).

Comment: `fn main() {
    let s = String::from("ADOBECODEBANC");
    let mut iter = s.chars().peekable();
    let k1 = *iter.peek().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}",k1);
    let k2 = *iter.peek().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}",k2);
}`
why this code is not calling next() than ?

Comment: @ShivamVarshney it does call `next` though, but on the underlying `Chars` iterator. Just like your original code calls `next` on the underlying `Peekable<Chars>` iterator of `it1`

Comment: @ShivamVarshney It is. I literally posted the actual code. `peek` memoises the value it gets the first time around, so the first call to `peek()` calls `next()` on the underlying `s.chars()` iterable, and the second call to `peek` gets the memoised value from `self.peeked`.